# C / Zsh – Something closes File Descriptor created by Zsh to connect programs

Tags: c, sockets, pipe, zsh, file-descriptor

I've written Zsh module. There I have a **builtin** – function mapped to Zsh command. This function duplicates its `stdin` file descriptor:

```
/* Duplicate standard input */
oconf->stream = fdopen( dup( fileno( stdin ) ), "r" );
```

Then I create a thread that reads the descriptor (`oconf->stream`):

```
/* Run the thread */
if ( pthread_create( &workers[ oconf->id ], NULL, process_input, oconf ) ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Error creating thread\n" );

    free_oconf( oconf );
    return 1;
}
```

In that thread I read `oconf->stream`, it works. When I'm closing the descriptor (in the same thread):

```
if ( -1 != fcntl( fileno( oconf->stream ), F_GETFD ) ) {
    if ( 0 != fclose( oconf->stream ) ) {
```

I sometimes get "Bad descriptor" error. That's the reason for the `fcntl()` check before `fclose()`, without it much more errors were generated. Turns out that adding `sleep()`:

```
if ( -1 != fcntl( fileno( oconf->stream ), F_GETFD ) ) {
    sleep( 1 );
    if ( 0 != fclose( oconf->stream ) ) {
```

"restores" the large amount of errors. So there's a race condition, something is closing the file descriptor between `fcntl()` and `fclose()`. **My question**:

*Is it possible that when writer process ends, the pipe created between stdout of writer <-> stdin of reader, gets invalidated on the other end automatically?*

The code I pasted is from the "stdin reader". I read data from `stdin` (duplicated to `oconf->stream`) and finish by closing by `fclose()`. Zsh creates a writer and `stdout` <-> `stdin` connection when I do `cat /some/data.txt | my_reader_builtin`.